# React Form issue with JSON

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with fields formatted like so

```
                  <Form.Field>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="firstname" 
                        placeholder="First Name" 
                        value= { this.state.user.firstname } 
                        onChange= { this.onChange } 
                    />
                  </Form.Field>
```

This works fine.  My onChange event manages this perfectly.

```
 state = {
    user: { 
      firstname: "",
      lastname: ""
   }
 }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      user: { ...this.state.user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
     });
  }
```

Originally, I had attempted to have my JSON object returned from my API with a nested hierarchy around name.

```
 state = {
    user: { 
     name: {
      firstname: "",
      lastname: ""
     }
   }
 }
```

But when it's like this, my onChange object adds variables to my state rather than managing the existing ones; even though events fire, I'm not changing the value on the UI. I attempted to navigate the JSON hierarchy by manipulating the name of the form.field to match the JSON but that didn't work:

```
                  <Form.Field>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="name.firstname" 
                    placeholder="First Name" 
                    value= { this.state.user.name.firstname } 
                    onChange= { this.onChange } 
                />
              </Form.Field>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is good, you can't navigate your JSON object in react using this syntax: `{ [e.target.name]: e.target.value }`

The simplest solution is to use a different `onChange` function that modifies specifically your `name` sub-object.

If you still want to have a single function, it should be possible to parse the `e.target.name` value and split the string on `.` character, but it sounds odd to me.